# Load mySQL results in arrays into a array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I can't figure out how to load the mySQL results (address,name) into this format:

```
$to=array(
    array("address"=>"johndoe@domain.ext","name"=>"John Doe"),
    array("address"=>"jofrost@domain.ext","name"=>"Jo Frost"),
    array("address"=>"someone@domain.ext","name"=>"Some One"),
    etc...
);
```

Please the old way for learning.
Thx.

Comment: It would be helpful to see what code you have currently and what it outputs.

Comment: How are you getting this ?

Comment: Do you want to load data into this format from dbase? If so its just fetchAll in all dbase providers.

Comment: It's a demo script I like to adjust, so the code above is inside but I have my data in a mySQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like that

```
$query = 'SELECT address, name FROM table';
$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'password', 'database');

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo 'Connect failed:' . $mysqli->connect_error;
    exit();
}

if($res = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    $ret = [];
    while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
       $ret[] = $row;
    }

    print_r($ret);

 } else {
      echo $mysqli->error;
 }
```

see more:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Thanks... but the only output I got is: Array ( )

Comment: How do you do a database query?

Comment: What do you mean? I just test your code copy/paste with, ofcourse, the right variables for table, database etc.

Comment: make another copy/paste

Comment: I found out: you forgot the () behind fetch_assoc, it works, thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's just a mistake, I fixed. If it works, please mark the answer